# Appending JSON file in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": "9 School Rd"    
}
```

how do I append this file in node.js? When I try fs.appendFile the JSON file ends up looking like this

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": "9 School Rd"    
}, 
"nickname": "shmee"
```

however this is obviously not what I want it to look like. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to add the `"nickname"` property to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way of doing this would be to parse in the object as JSON then save back the stringified version to the file.

```
var data = require('./my-data-file.json'); // Will automatically parse JSON
data.nickname = "shmee";
fs.writeFile('./my-data-file.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), options, callback);
```

The [options and callback are optional](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) but I suggest writing a callback because that will let you know when the data has been saved.

Comment: can you do this with variables? for example if nickname was instead a key, and "shmee" was a value could i do

data[key] = value; 

and then the rest